# Group the rows in a datatable using linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public static void ShortFall(List<Dictionary<string, string>> Data)
    {
        List<dynamic> RetData = new List<dynamic>();
        DataTable dtstock = new DataTable();
        DBHelper.DBhelpercls db = new DBHelper.DBhelpercls();
        List<dynamic> ShortfallTempArray = new List<dynamic>();
        List<dynamic> ShortfallTempArray2 = new List<dynamic>();
        List<dynamic> ShortfallArray = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> EachItems in Data)
        {
            dtstock = db.GetTable("SELECT ISNULL(Qty,0) AS Stock_Qnty FROM TBLActualStock WHERE ItemCode='" + EachItems["ItemCode"].ToString() + "' AND Mode=1");
            if (dtstock.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                ShortfallTempArray.Add(new { ItemCode = EachItems["ItemCode"].ToString(), ItemDesc = EachItems["ItemDesc"].ToString(), Qty =EachItems["Qty"].ToString(), Uom = EachItems["Unit"].ToString() });
            }
            else if (((Convert.ToSingle(dtstock.Rows[0]["Stock_Qnty"].ToString()) - Convert.ToSingle(EachItems["Qty"].ToString())) <= 0))
            {
                ShortfallTempArray.Add(new { ItemCode = EachItems["ItemCode"].ToString(), ItemDesc = EachItems["ItemDesc"].ToString(), Qty = (Convert.ToSingle(dtstock.Rows[0]["Stock_Qnty"].ToString()) - Convert.ToSingle(EachItems["Qty"].ToString())).ToString(), Uom = EachItems["Unit"].ToString() });
            }
        }

        var summary = from p in ShortfallTempArray
                      let k = new
                      {
                          ItemCode = p.ItemCode,
                          ItemDesc = p.ItemDesc,
                          Uom = p.Uom
                      }
                      group p by k into t
                      select new
                      {
                          ItemCode = t.Key.ItemCode,
                          ItemDesc = t.Key.ItemDesc,
                          Uom = t.Key.Uom,
                          Qty = t.Sum(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.Qty)) 
                      };
        foreach (var row in summary)
        {
            ShortfallTempArray2.Add(new { ItemCode = row.ItemCode, ItemDesc = row.ItemDesc, Qty = row.Qty.ToString(), Uom=row.Uom });
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Short"] = ShortfallTempArray2;
    }
```

In the above code when the Qty is an integer then it works properly;
But if it float or decimal the below line stuck with error.

```
Qty = t.Sum(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.Qty))
```

I just Change `Convert.ToInt32` to `Convert.ToDouble` then the below error appears....

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What is p.Qty datatype ?

Comment: Your code works fine for me for all combinations of `Qty` being an `int` or `double` and the `Convert` call being `Convert.ToInt32` or `Convert.ToDouble`.

Comment: Why do you need the cast in the first place? The error you show doesn't really match the code. Are you actually trying to project to a known type where `Qty` is an `int`?

Comment: Now I Place my entire code there. Please go through it.

Comment: @JeffMercado Please Check my entire code

Comment: Well there's your problem... you're mixing up the types in that collection (among other things). Don't, there's no need to.

Comment: Try the following Qty = Convert.ToInt32(t.Sum(p => p.Qty))

Answer (score 0):

probably the error is of the Qty datatype as it should be of integer type.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably trying to do:

> (int)=(double)

you should do:

```
Qty = (int)t.Sum(p => Convert.ToDouble(p.Qty));
```

Or change the type of Qty to double

Comment: Still The error Exist. In my database datatype of Qty is float